# Php json decoding with multiple objects

Tags: php, html, json, api, decode

**Json**

```
{
    "articles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Josh" 
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jenny"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Chris"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do i search names by id?
What should I do if i want select only Josh?

Now I'm decoding json with php and foreach loop.

```
$url = "articles.json";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
foreach($json->articles as $articles){
    echo $articles->name;
}
```

I want select only that name where id is 1.

Comment: You would have to do a forloop. If you want to search through a kind of query, you'll need to use a framework like jql, jsonpath, or a bigger framework that has json querying inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $url = "articles.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    foreach($json->articles as $articles){
        if($articles->id==1){
           echo "found id equal to 1";
    }
        if($articles->name=="Josh"){
           echo "found Josh";
    }
    }
```

Even better as a small function for `fieldValue` (`id` or `name`) with `url`, `checkValue` as additional parameters

```
   Function loopThruJSON ($json,$fieldValue,$checkValue) {
        $json = json_decode($json);
        foreach($json->articles as $articles){
            if($articles->{$fieldValue}==$checkValue){
               return "found ".$fieldValue." equal to ".$checkValue;
            } else {
               return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Based on [FirstOne's](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df31523865a39377e0a431fb3e6843c745d8e42f) comment + example the above can be written

```
    Function loopThruJSON ($json,$fieldValue,$checkValue) {
            $json = json_decode($json);
            foreach($json->articles as $articles){
                if($articles->$fieldValue==$checkValue){
                   return "found ".$fieldValue." equal to ".$checkValue;
                } else {
                   return false;
                }
            }
     }
// Usage
echo loopThruJSONID ("articles.json",'id',1) ;
echo loopThruJSONName ("articles.json",'name',"Josh") ;
```

[PHP sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df31523865a39377e0a431fb3e6843c745d8e42f), [3v4l example](https://3v4l.org/UqE8n)

Comment: That won't work (the function part)... by the time you call the function, there is no `$articles->id`...

Comment: @FirstOne you are right what on earth am i writing :) one moment

Comment: @FirstOne deleted that please edit the answer accordingly thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$json = '{
    "articles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Josh" 
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jenny"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Chris"
        }
    ]
}';

$json = json_decode($json);
$id = '1';
$result = 'NOT FOUND';
foreach($json->articles as $articles){
    if($articles->id == $id){
        $result = $articles;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

output:

> stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => Josh )

That way you keep both the `id` and the `name` tied.

Access it normaly, like so: `echo $result->name;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_filter` to get every item in the array with the id you want.

```
$id = 1;  // define your id

// filter for that id
$results = array_filter($json->articles, function($x) use ($id) {
    return $x->id == $id;
});
```

The result will be an array with zero or more elements, depending on how many times the id is found. I'm not sure what you need to do with the results, but you can loop over them with foreach, or access specific elements by key like this:

```
echo $results[0]->name;   // echo the name of the first match
```

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty easy:

```
function findById($articles, $id){
    foreach($articles as $article){
        if($article['id'] === $id)
           return $article;
    }
}
```

In this answer, you will need to pass `true` as a second parameter of `json_decode()` in order convert the data into associative arrays.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
```

Comment: A side note, you call also use it as object (without the `true` in the json_decode) by changing from `$article['id']` to `$article->id`.

Comment: @FirstOne Yea I know, but I find the other one easier to read, I dont like that one dunno why